# GAE - Getting TypeError requiring class instance be passed to class's own method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, class, methods, typeerror

I'm really new to programming... I set up a class to give supporting information for Google's User API user object. I store this info in the datastore using db.model.

When I call the okstatus method of my user_info class using this code:

```
elif user_info.okstatus(user):
    self.response.out.write("user allowed")
```

I get this error:

```
unbound method okstatus() must be called with user_info instance
as first argument (got User instance instead)
```

Here is my user_info class.

```
class user_info:
    def auth_ctrlr(self, user):
        if self.status(user) == status_allowed:
            return ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign Out</a>)" %
                (users.create_login_url("/")))
        else:
            return ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign In or Get an Account</a>)" %
                (users.create_logout_url("/")))
    def status(self, user):
        match = sub_user.gql(qu_by_user_id, user.user_id)
        return match.string_status
    def group(self, user):
        match = sub_user.gql(qu_by_user_id, user.user_id)
        grp = group_names.gql(qu_by_user_id, match.groupID)
        return grp
    def okstatus(self, user):
        match = self.status(user)
        if match == status_allowed:
            return True
```

My understanding is that the argument "self" inside the method's calling arguments describes it as a child to the class. I've tried everything I can think of and can't find any related info online. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` must be an instance of the class.  Since you never actually **use** it, you can simply make all of these methods into functions (and changing the `self.status` cases to just `status`).

If you're a "class fetishist", and absolutely insist on keeping the functions as methods in a class (rather than the module top-level functions they "want" to be!-), then change the call site to

```
elif user_info().okstatus(user):
```

that is, make an instance of your `user_info` class, and call the method on it (the useless instance then immediately goes away, pointing out that these should really be functions;-).

Comment: You are very correct. Thanks for helping me really understand the situation. I'll take your advice and functionize them.